# Caret in method call

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was going through this tutorial and came across this line of code which has stumped me:

```
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
            MKMapItem *mapItem = [response.mapItems objectAtIndex:i];
            [self.mapItems addObject:mapItem];
            i++;
        } while (i < response.mapItems.count);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Address Found" object:self];
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Not Found" object:self];
    }
}];
```

The part which I don't understand is the following: `^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {`

That caret symbol  `^`  and what is happening after that is what I don't know.

I looked through some documentation but could not find anything.

Comment: Basically it's a function/method embedded inside another function/method. It has similar scope rules to an if/for/while/switch block. The code inside can access variables outside the block, as if they were part of the parent block (there are some additional complexities though)

Answer (score 6):

**^** denotes a **block** in objective c. It is like an anonymous function that can be assigned to a variable or being passed as an argument to a function as seen in your example. Read more in the Apple docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

**Defining a block:**

```
 ^{
     NSLog(@"This is a block");
}
```

**Assigning a block to a variable:**

```
void (^simpleBlock)(void);

// or

simpleBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"This is a block");
};
```

**Calling a block:**

```
simpleBlock();
```

**Using a block as an argument for a message:**

```
- (IBAction)fetchRemoteInformation:(id)sender {
    [self showProgressIndicator];

    XYZWebTask *task = ...

    [task beginTaskWithCallbackBlock:^{
        [self hideProgressIndicator];
    }];
}
```

Examples are taken from the Apple documentation

Answer (score 3):

The `^` indicates a **block** - a set of code that can be passed around like a variable.

In your example:

```
^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) { ... }
  |---------------------------------------------|   |---|
     Arguments (you can use these in the block)       ^ Code goes here
```

Since you are using a completion handler, your block doesn't return anything to it's caller. The MapKit search thingy calls all the code in that block when it's done searching.

There's a nice document from Apple on the subject [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html).